# Using Matrix to create a dynamic header in R

Tags: r

I computed column sum and I wanted to insert the result in a matrix without doing it manually. But it seems not to work.

Below is my code and the result I obtained thereafter

```
      t5

 Status A B

 Rare   3 4

 Str    4 8

 Grp    9 10

N1<-sum(t5[,"A"])
N2<-sum(t5[,"B"])
header<- matrix(c( "Standard(N=N1)", "New(N=N2)", "", ""), nrow=1, ncol=5)
```

Result obtained is:

```
header
     [,1]             [,2]        [,3]          [,4] [,5]
[1,] "Standard(N=N1)" "New(N=N2)" ""   ""
```

But what I actually wanted was the value of `N1`, `N2` and `N3` in `Standard` and `New` rather than `N1` and `N2`.

Please how I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example of t5 please?

Comment: create some dummy data for us to use @Jyde

Comment: Could you add what your desired output should look like? I think you are simply looking for `cbind` but I am not completely sure.

Comment: You're trying to pass an expression as a character string (assuming `Standard()` and `New()` are function names), but you never evaluate that expression. Try something like `eval(parse(text="Standard(N=N1)"))` instead. For further reading, see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html